authOptions problem in NextJS + TypeScript with MongoDB
Having difficulties building my code. Thinking it has something to do with authOptions. I can run npm run dev without a problem, but can't build it npm run build.
Here is my 'route.js' file located in 'app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js'
import { connectMongoDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/user";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},

      async authorize(credentials) {
        const {email, password} = credentials;

        try {
          await connectMongoDB();
          const user = await User.findOne({ email });
          
          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

          if (!passwordsMatch) {
            return null;
          }

          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error: ", error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages:{
    signIn: "/login",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

I'm using it in my code to get session status to display different text depending whether a user is logged in or not.
'AboutPage.tsx' file from 'app/components/AboutPage.tsx'
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

export default async function AboutPage() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

then using it here
{!session && <Link href="/login" className="links">Login</Link>}
{session && <Link href="/dashboard"><span style = {{ fontWeight: 700}} className="links">Welcome, {session?.user?.name}</span></Link>}

I get the error:
Property 'authOptions' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ providers: CredentialsConfig<{}>[]; session: { strategy: string; }; secret: string | undefined; pages: { signIn: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
I've tried converting the route.js file to route.ts, but I encountered more problems.
